# Manage / run commands in a NXT (nxtcoin) client/server via the command line in Linux?

Tags: php, nxt

I have nxt (nxtcoin) server installed, but since its built completely different from Bitcoin and uses Java. How do you use the command line to control a NXT client to send, generate addresses, etc?

I want to use this for interfacing with a PHP cms system (drupal) and curious how to interface with the NXT system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to figure this out too.

Instead of running the server interface at http://127.0.0.1:7876 try http://127.0.0.1:7876/test . Looks like a bunch of API calls. I'm playing with it right now.

Answer (score 1):

use curl

for instance:

> curl -s --data "requestType=getAlias&aliasName=google" http://127.0.0.1:7876/nxt

So in PHP

> $cmd = 'curl -s --data "requestType=getAlias&aliasName=google" http://127.0.0.1:7876/nxt';
>   $jsonString = exec($cmd);